# android not getting correct TimeStamp

Tags: android, timezone, timestamp

I am using on method but not getting correct time stamp

```
long dateToTimestamp = Common.dateToTimestamp("Mon, 14 Dec 2015 10:20:37 GMT", "EE, dd MMM yyy HH:mm:dd zz");

public static final long dateToTimestamp(String date, String format) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                format);
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(getDefaultTimeZone());
        Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);

        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(
                parsedDate.getTime());
        return timestamp.getTime() / 1000;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}

public static final TimeZone getDefaultTimeZone() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    return cal.getTimeZone();
}
```

but not getting correct timestamp.

Comment: timestamp means you want current datetime?

Comment: no, timestamp means current millisecond ..

Comment: ok.wait i am sending you line of code.

Comment: okay first you check with my date String and formate please..
Right time stamp is =  1450088437 but my code give me other value

Comment: dateToTimestamp return long value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out,Which works for me,

```
String givenDateString = "Tue Apr 23 16:08:28 GMT+05:30 2013"; 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
try {
    Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
    long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
    System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
} catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thank you it work perfect.
my problem is Date Formate i am set wrong.

Comment: Happy to help...keep happy coding